# Customizing the order of legends in plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, bar-chart, plotly, legend

I am trying to customize the order of legends while plotting stacked bar plots in plotly,python.

```
data = [
        go.Bar(
            y=df['sid'],  # assign x as the dataframe column 'x'
            x=df['A'],
            orientation='h',
            name='A'
        ),
        go.Bar(
            y=df['sid'],
            x=df['B'],
            orientation='h',
            name='B'
        ),

    ]

    layout = go.Layout(
        barmode='stack',
        title=f'{measurement}',
        xaxis=dict(
            title='Count',
            dtick=0),
        yaxis=dict(
            tickfont=dict(
                size=10,
            ),
            dtick=1)
    )

    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    plot(fig, filename='plot.html')
```

The order of the legend appears in the reverse order(i.e from bottom to top). I want to change the order from top to bottom of the corresponding items in `data`.

I saw the option suggested [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/customizing-the-order-of-legends/12668) for java. Not sure how to implement in python.

Could someone suggest how the order can be reversed?

EDIT:
In the image that is generated the order of legend is

```
B
A
```

Desired order:

```
A
B
```

Comment: Could you please provide an image representing the result you got and the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: @sentence Please check the edit

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [`traceorder`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-legend-traceorder) key for legend:

> Determines the order at which the legend items are displayed. If
>   "normal", the items are displayed top-to-bottom in the same order as
>   the input data. If "reversed", the items are displayed in the opposite
>   order as "normal". If "grouped", the items are displayed in groups
>   (when a trace `legendgroup` is provided). if "grouped+reversed", the
>   items are displayed in the opposite order as "grouped".

In your case, you should modify your `layout` definition:

```
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    title=f'{measurement}',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Count',
        dtick=0),
    yaxis=dict(
        tickfont=dict(
            size=10,
        ),
        dtick=1),
   legend={'traceorder':'normal'})
)
```

---

**without traceorder specification**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace1 = go.Bar(x=['A', 'B', 'C'],
                y=[20, 14, 23],
                name='first')
trace2 = go.Bar(x=['A', 'B', 'C'],
                y=[12, 18, 29],
                name='second')

data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(barmode='stack',)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig, filename='stacked-bar')
```

[image]

**with traceorder specification**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace1 = go.Bar(x=['A', 'B', 'C'],
                y=[20, 14, 23],
                name='first')
trace2 = go.Bar(x=['A', 'B', 'C'],
                y=[12, 18, 29],
                name='second')

data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(barmode='stack',
                   legend={'traceorder':'normal'})

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig, filename='stacked-bar')
```

[image]

Comment: FYI `go.Legend` has been deprecated in favor of `go.layout.Legend`

Answer (score 11):

You can only add this line to reverse the current order of legend labels:

```
fig.update_layout(legend_traceorder="reversed")
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone found this answer looking for a solution using `plotly` in `R`, it is `legend = list(traceorder="normal"),` in the `layout()` block.