# Order of legend plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Just like a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808693/customizing-the-order-of-legends-in-plotly), I would like to change the order of the legend of a plotly pie chart. The difference is that I can't simply use `traceorder` since I have more than 6 labels and reversing them doesn't put them in the right order.

Is there a way to customize the order?

As an example with 4 labels:

```py
import plotly.offline as py
trace1 = go.Pie(                    
    values = [2, 4, 4, 9],                    
    labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    name    = "Succes" 
)

data = [trace1]
fig  = go.Figure(data = data)
py.plot(fig)
```

[image: How it's currently]

I would like to prespecify the order of the legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Seems like your best bet is to either reorder the input/column to the way that you want it *prior* to plotting it, as Plotly will then just reference that order.

OR

> > Try and use traceorder (specifically Grouped) as @Massifox mentions.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the only control that is available right now is the `layout.legend.traceorder` attribute in the plotly [docs](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-legend-traceorder)

Answer (score 1):

For pie charts, the legend and the slice order are linked, and by default the slices are sorted. To disable sorting, you can set `sort=False` inside `go.Pie()`, which will cause your slices and the corresponding legend to appear in the order you specify in your data arrays.