# order plotly legend by custom order

Tags: pandas, plotly

I have a plotly figure to which I add values from two dataframes, df_a and df_b. I display both dataframes in different subplots, but they share a legend. How can I order the shared legend? The expected order is: [a, b, c, f, g]. Please see below for the current implementation - it seems to pick the order from input data in some way.

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import iplot

df_a = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "a", "b", "c"], data=[
    [pd.to_datetime("31Jan20"), 3, 4, 5],
    [pd.to_datetime("31Mar20"), 3, 4, 5],
    [pd.to_datetime("30Jun20"), 3, 4, 5],
])

df_b = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "a", "g", "f"], data=[
    [pd.to_datetime("31Jan20"), 8, 5, 4],
    [pd.to_datetime("31Mar20"), 3, 4, 5],
    [pd.to_datetime("30Jun20"), 3, 4, 5],
])

buckets = ["a", "b", "c", "f", "g"]

fig_subplots = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, subplot_titles=["df_a", "df_b"])

def get_chart(df, buckets, d_legend):
    fig = go.Figure()
    colorscale = px.colors.qualitative.Pastel
    i_color = 0
    unique_dates = [str(dt) for dt in df.date.unique()]
    for bucket in sorted(buckets, reverse=True):

        y_values = df[df['variable'] == bucket]["value"].to_list()
        enable_legend_for_bucket = False if bucket in d_legend else True

        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            name=bucket,
            x=unique_dates,
            y=y_values,
            marker_color=colorscale[i_color],
            legendgroup=bucket,   
            showlegend=enable_legend_for_bucket

        ))

        if len(y_values) != 0:
            d_legend[bucket] = True # store first time this bucket was populated for legend  

        i_color += 1
      
    fig.update_layout(barmode="stack")       
    return fig, d_legend

list_df = [df_a.melt(id_vars="date"), df_b.melt(id_vars="date")]
d_legend = {}
iRow = 1
for df in list_df:
    fig, d_legend = get_chart(df, buckets, d_legend)
    
    for el in fig['data']:
        fig_subplots.append_trace(el, iRow, 1)
    iRow += 1
fig_subplots.update_layout(barmode='stack', legend={'traceorder':'normal'})
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to customize legend order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61546556/plotly-how-to-customize-legend-order)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help - the final order of the legend is made up of elements from different dataframes - even if I sort the individual dataframes (see updated code), the legend will sort based on the order of the dataframes

Comment: If `for bucket in sorted(buckets):`, the legends are arranged in alphabetical order. On the other hand, why is `reverse=True` used?

Comment: @r-beginners: good point, that seems to fix it, it was the interaction between this sorting in each dataframe and the combined legend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without finding an easy built-in method to order the legend, and to have the same stacking of values with the legend sorted in any desired order.

```
new_order = sorted(['a','b','c','g','f'],reverse=True)
print(new_order)

 
ordered_object_list =[]
for i in new_order:
    item = [obj for obj in fig_subplots.data if obj['name'] == i]
    ordered_object_list += item

 
fig_subplots.data = ordered_object_list
fig_subplots.update_layout(legend={'traceorder':'reversed'})
```

Comment: I prefer this approach: it sorts the traces after they have been combined into a figure, so no need to get the inputs right

Comment: It also gives the ability to have a custom sort order that is not ascending or descending, but based on a custom comparator

Answer (score 0):

There is also an approach with plotly express:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df_a = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "a", "b", "c"], data=[
    [pd.to_datetime("31Jan20"), 3, 4, 5],
    [pd.to_datetime("31Mar20"), 3, 4, 5],
    [pd.to_datetime("30Jun20"), 3, 4, 5],
])

df_b = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "a", "g", "f"], data=[
    [pd.to_datetime("31Jan20"), 8, 5, 4],
    [pd.to_datetime("31Mar20"), 3, 4, 5],
    [pd.to_datetime("30Jun20"), 3, 4, 5],
])

df_a["id"] = "df_a"
df_b["id"] = "df_b"
df_c = df_a.append(df_b)
px.bar(df_c.melt(id_vars=["date", "id"]), x="date", y="value", color="variable", facet_col="id", range_y=[0,20], facet_col_wrap=1)
```

[image]