# Reverse legend order without changing bar order in plotly express bar plot

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I'd like to change the order of the items in the legend of a `plotly.express` bar plot.
For example, I'd like to show Dinner before Lunch on this plot (the current behavior is especially awkward with horizontal bar plots, since the order of the bars is the opposite of the legend order):

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
# Sort to put dinner on top.
df.sort_values('time', ascending=False, inplace=True)
fig = px.bar(df, y='sex', x='total_bill', color='time', barmode='group',
             orientation='h')
fig.update_layout(yaxis={'categoryorder': 'total ascending'})
fig.show()
```

[image: plot result]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customizing the order of legends in plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808693/customizing-the-order-of-legends-in-plotly)

Comment: @vestland I don't think so, it's not using `plotly.express` and while it mentions `traceorder` it doesn't suggest the simple answer I provided, `legend={'traceorder': 'reversed'}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add [`legend={'traceorder': 'reversed'}`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-legend-traceorder) to the `update_layout` statement:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
# Sort to put dinner on top.
df.sort_values('time', ascending=False, inplace=True)
fig = px.bar(df, y='sex', x='total_bill', color='time', barmode='group',
             orientation='h')
fig.update_layout(yaxis={'categoryorder': 'total ascending'},
                  legend={'traceorder': 'reversed'})
fig.show()
```

[image: result of plot]