# Python Plotly legend display in ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have created a code which displays a graph along with legend. The legend by default is not in any specific order. I need to order it in ascending order. But did not get any useful link for that.
Is there a way to do that?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time_list, y=list1,name="<b>" + entityName + "</b>", connectgaps=False))
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, height=650, width=1400, title='<b>Availability</b>'
                  ,xaxis_title='<b>Date</b>', yaxis_title='<b>Percentage</b>')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [traceorder](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-legend-traceorder).
An example would be:

```
layout = go.Layout(
   legend={'traceorder':'normal'})
)
```

You can view a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808693/customizing-the-order-of-legends-in-plotly).

Comment: "normal" - the items are displayed top-to-bottom in the same order as the input data. Traceorder is not helping here.